# IBM X3650 M3 occasional PCIe-related errors on reboot

Tags: hardware, ibm, ibm-xseries

Intermittently, this system will fail to POST and boot loop repeatedly (sometimes for hours) without making it past the BIOS screen. The errors appear to be PCIe related, but no additional PCIe cards are installed. When the errors occur, the LightPath display shows a single LED for `PCI`. The error LEDs on both PCIe risers are unlit. The IMM logs some combination of the following messages:

- `Fault in slot "All PCI Error" on system "..."`
- `A software NMI has occurred on system "..."`
- `A Uncorrectable Bus Error has occurred on system "..."`

Completely powering down the system and disconnecting power for a minute or so sometimes helps.

Interestingly, once the system makes it past the initial BIOS screens to OS loading, generally it will finish booting and run 100% stable for weeks to months.

Comment: It seem to me a motherboard failure possibly coming. Do you have burstout condensator on the mainboard ? as heretic symptom like that remind me of condensator that can't take the load, and possibly can after some time.

Comment: By condensator, do you mean capacitor? I will take a look around inside later to see if anything looks out of the ordinary.

Comment: Oh yes, I did a bad translation there, capacitor are named condensateur in French, sorry

Comment: Also I'd clean the server with compressed air. Just to be sure there is no conductive dust possibly shorting something.